# How can I dynamically set mouse tool to canvas coordinates?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I have a canvas that I am using to draw on with the mouse and then saving the drawing as an image. I need a little help in setting the mouse tool's function's coordinates to that of the canvas' coordinates.

Here is the function that sets the mouse to the canvas.

```
        function ev_canvas(ev) {
            ev._x = ev.layerX;
            ev._y = ev.layerY;

        var func = tool[ev.type];
        if (func) {
            func(ev);
        }
    }
```

This works if I have the canvas located at the top left corner. I need this function to set the mouse's interaction coordinates dynamically.

The problem is, when I set the page to use the style sheet, the function is not adjusting to the styled location of the canvas. I can subtract the difference from the coordinates of the canvas like this and it works for the particular maximized resolution of my computer.

```
        function ev_canvas(ev) {
            ev._x = ev.layerX - 760;
            ev._y = ev.layerY - 130;

        var func = tool[ev.type];
        if (func) {
            func(ev);
        }
    }
```

How can I set this function to work no matter where the canvas is located on the screen?

**EDIT**

Here is the complete javascript:

```
if (window.addEventListener) {
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    var canvas, context, tool;

    function init() {

        canvas = document.getElementById('digisigBox');
        if (!canvas) {
            alert('Error: I cannot find the canvas element!');
            return;
        }

        if (!canvas.getContext) {
            alert('Error: no canvas.getContext!');
            return;
        }

        context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        if (!context) {
            alert('Error: failed to getContext!');
            return;
        }

        tool = new tool_pencil();

        canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', ev_canvas, false);
        canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', ev_canvas, false);
        canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', ev_canvas, false);
    }

    function tool_pencil() {
        var tool = this;
        this.started = false;

        this.mousedown = function (ev) {
            context.beginPath();
            context.moveTo(ev._x, ev._y);
            tool.started = true;
        };

        this.mousemove = function (ev) {
            if (tool.started) {
                context.lineTo(ev._x, ev._y);
                context.stroke();
            }
        };

        this.mouseup = function (ev) {
            if (tool.started) {
                tool.mousemove(ev);
                tool.started = false;
            }
        };
    }


    function ev_canvas(ev) {

        ev._x = ev.clientX;
        ev._y = ev.clientY;

        var func = tool[ev.type];
        if (func) {
            func(ev);
        }
    }

    init();

}, false);
```

}

This is where I use it within my view/html:

```
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/digisig.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div id="container">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Create_Signature"))
    {
        <div style="margin: auto; text-align: center;">
            <canvas id="digisigBox" width="400" height="200">
            </canvas>
          <script type="text/javascript">
                function putImage() {
                    var canvas = document.getElementById("digisigBox");
                    if (canvas.getContext) {
                        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
                        var myImage = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
                    }
                    var imageElement = document.getElementById("Signature");
                    imageElement.value = myImage;
                }
            </script>
            @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Signature)
        </div>       
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.FirstName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.FirstName)
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.LastName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.LastName)
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <input id="submit" onclick="putImage()" type="submit" value="Submit" />
    }
</div>
```

What this does is creates an image from the drawing on the canvas and then the image is stored as a base64 after postback. I'm just not sure how to get the mouse to work within the canvas on various resolutions. If the canvas was going to be located at coords(0,0) this would work perfectly, but the canvas may need to move around from page to page.

Comment: What do you mean, set the mouse to the canvas?  Are you trying to move the users mouse, or are you just trying to figure out when a user clicks/hovers over your mouse area?

Comment: I'm trying to get the mouseup and mousedown functions to work with the canvas only when the mouse is within the canvases borders.